# How to stop using onload() function to avoid loosing the PHP output when page refreshed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onload

I'm using the onload() function to avoid loosing the PHP output when the page is refreshed. I'm trying to avoid the shaking effects caused by the onload function. I haven't yet found any alternative way to do that. How can I achieve the same affect without using *onload*?

### **file.js**

```
function showMe(){
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "output.php",  
         cache: false,       
         data: "action=showMessage",        
         success: function(html){                
            $("#container").html(html);  
          }
   });

return false;
}
```

### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
</head>
     <body onload="showMe();">
            <div id="container"></div>
            <form id="myForm"></form>
     </body>
</html>
```

### output.php

```
  if ($action=="showMessage")
  {   
         $query="SELECT * FROM `comm` ORDER BY id ASC";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

           if (isset($_REQUEST['parentId'])) { 
                  $parentId = $_REQUEST['parentId']; 
             }
          else { $parentId = 0; }

             $i=0;  $my = array();
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 
               $my[$i] = $row; $i++; 
         }
      tree($my, 0, $parentId);
      }

   function tree($Array, $lvl, $ansId, $pid = 0) 
   {   $parentId = $ansId;

      foreach($Array as $item)
      {
         if ($item[1] == $pid) 
         {  ?>            
               <div style="margin-left:<?php echo($lvl*40); ?>px">    
               <p><?php echo($item[3]); ?></p>
               <?php  
                    if ($lvl<=4){ echo '<a href="javascript:" onclick="OneComment('.$item[0].');">Reply</a>'; }
               ?> </div> <?php 
           tree($Array, $lvl+1,$parentId, $item[0]);
         }       
      }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: where does `$action` get set? is it set to `$_POST['action']` when that is defined/set? And what do you mean by _shaking effects caused by onload function_? a literal _shaking_ effect?

Comment: yes, the $action is set to $_REQUEST['action'];, But, when I remove onload="showMe()" on the body tag, The output disappeared

Comment: so you still want to have the asynchronous call but without using _onload_? by _shaking effects_ do you mean that the text doesn't appear until after the page loads?

Comment: Personally I would change it to `<div id="container"><?php require __DIR__ . '/output;php'; ?></div>`. And change the `onload`, to the `submit` event of the form. e.g: `jQuery(function($){ $('#myForm').on('submit', showMe); });` That way you initially load the output without Javascript, and still maintain the ajax functionality when the form is submitted.

Comment: To expand on my comment, add a check for output.php to check `if (!array_key_exists('action', $_POST)) { $action = 'showMessage'; } else { $action = $_POST['action']; }` to ensure the default javascript functionality of `showMe` is retained.

Comment: I mean whwn the form was submitted the message displayed, But when I reload the page the messages disappear until I add Onload events to the body.. Personally I don't like the effects caused by Onload event,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to have the JavaScript code set a cookie and then have the PHP code that renders the HTML check to see if that cookie is set.

For example, when the form is submitted (presuming that it calls the `showMe()` function and stops the form from submitting manually with [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)), set a cookie with [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(submitEvent) {
    //Store cookie, which can be accessed via PHP on next page-load
    document.cookie = 'formSubmitted=1';
    showMe();
    return false;//don't submit form
});
```

Then when index.php is reloaded, check for that cookie using the [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) variable [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['formSubmitted'])  && $_COOKIE['formSubmitted']==1) {
    //output the messsages (in the div with id="container"), using the code from output.php
    //perhaps abstracting that code into a common function that can be used
    //in both places
}
```

See an example of this in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/umri-r913). Keep in mind that phpFiddle only allows one php script in a fiddle so the code in output.php had to be moved into the top of that PHP script and run only if there was POST data (e.g. from the AJAX request). Otherwise the code in the files can be kept separate.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr Sam, This help me alots,But I have one question, How if the PHP and AJAX Outputs on the same page, In case I want to remove the echo output of php and the output using Ajax without refreshing the page? I there any way to hide php results and display them via ajax on the single/same page?

Comment: @Jackson see my updated explanation. You can keep the files separate. I just had to combine them because phpFiddle only allows one file per fiddle...